# How to mark "not fully installed" apt-get package as "successfully installed"

Tags: debian, apt, initramfs

I have installed Debian 7.4 on my Iomega ix2-200 NAS, following [this blog](http://blog.nobiscuit.com/2011/08/06/installing-debian-to-disk-on-an-ix2-200/). The ix2-200 is running an ARM Marvel CPU and has a 128 MB NAND flash memory. The flash contains an initramfs image (uInitrd) and a kernel image (uImage) to boot the system.

Sometimes, a new package (like `cryptsetup`) requieres to update the kernel and fails (`Unsupported platform`). I manually need to flash the new initramfs `initrd.img-3.2.0-4-kirkwood` and kernel `vmlinuz` via `mkimage`, which works fine.

The (anoying) issue: everytime I run `apt-get upgrade` the system is showing up those unfinished packages. **How can I tell my system that everything is fine?**

I have tried Google and StackExchange, but most of the posts are dealing with how to remove those unfinished/incomplete packages. I want to keep it!

Please see attached code snapshot:

```
#> apt-get install cryptsetup
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  console-setup console-setup-linux cryptsetup-bin kbd keyboard-configuration libcryptsetup4 xkb-data
Suggested packages:
  dosfstools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  console-setup console-setup-linux cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin kbd keyboard-configuration libcryptsetup4 xkb-data
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,179 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y

...

Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-kirkwood
Unsupported platform.
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//flash-kernel exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

#> apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Comment: The answer to "How can I tell my system that everything is fine?" is that you don't. Fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix `/etc/initramfs/post-update.d/flash-kernel` so that it successfully flashes your kernel & initrd. It's in /etc, so you're free to edit it to make it work on your board.

If you can't edit it to make it work (e.g., flashing is done with JTAG), then you ought to have it print out a big warning reminding you to flash it, and `exit 0`.

Once you've fixed it, then you can run `dpkg --configure -a`.

Answer (score 7):

ONLY IF YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING, you can manually tell dpkg that the package is installed.

You can edit package entry in /var/lib/dpkg/status file: set status line "Status: ok installed" (or "Status: hold ok installed" if you don't want to upgrade automatically next time).

Comment: Tampering with this file is a bad idea.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Status: install ok installed`?

I just did this to fix apt-get constantly trying to configure openssh-server because the configuration fails (I did the configuration manually).

Worked for me.

Comment: Yes @AustinFrance it should be.

Comment: I had to use "Status: install ok installed"
Tampering with this file was a necessity. Effective :)